# Error 9 en tiempo de ejecucion, sub indice fuera de intervalo

Tags: vba

```
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    CommandButton5.BackColor = 12713921

    '===========================================================================================
    '                                    VARIABLES
    '===========================================================================================
    'i = 1000
    'Do Until Cells(i, 2) = ""
    'If i < 10 Then
    'End If
    Dim py, pb, veltestactual, NFD, API, Tfondo, BSW, GravAgua, Pcasing, ViscoFluido, ProfBomba, PMP, Caudaltestactual, rppmoper, PIPtomado, Diametro As Double
    Dim THP, Voltaje, Corriente, FactorPotencia, LongitudCable, EffMotor, NumSellos, EffBomba As Double
    Dim n As Double
    Dim X1, X2, Y1, Y2, x As Double

    case1 = ActiveCell.Row
    cases = Selection.Rows.Count
    lastcase = case1 + cases - 1

    'Return
    For n = case1 To lastcase

    'Pwf = Cells(n, 24)
    py = Cells(n, 17)
    pb = Cells(n, 9)
    veltestactual = Cells(n, 35)
    NFD = Cells(n, 23)
    API = Cells(n, 6)
    Tfondo = Cells(n, 10)
    BSW = Cells(n, 8)
    GravAgua = 1
    Pcasing = Cells(n, 50)
    ViscoFluido = Cells(n, 13)
    ProfBomba = Cells(n, 29)
    PMP = Cells(n, 28)
    Caudaltestactual = Cells(n, 48)
    rpmoper = Cells(n, 34)
    PIPtomado = Cells(n, 40)
    Diametro = Cells(n, 31)
    THP = Cells(n, 51)
    Voltaje = Cells(n, 41)
    Corriente = Cells(n, 37)
    FactorPotencia = Cells(n, 47)
    LongitudCable = Cells(n, 42)
    EffMotor = Cells(n, 43)
    NumSellos = 2

    '=================================================================
    '               CALCULO DEL CAUDAL ACTUAL
    '=================================================================

    Caudalactual = Caudaltestactual * (rpmoper / veltestactual)
    '==================================================================
    '              EFFICIENCIA DE LA BOMBA
    '==================================================================
    Select Case Caudalactual

    Case Is < 500
    X1 = 0
    X2 = 500
    Y1 = 0
    Y2 = 30
    x = Caudalactual
    EffBomba = (((x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)) + Y1) / 100

    Case 500.01 To 1000
    X1 = 500.01
    X2 = 1000
    Y1 = 30
    Y2 = 46
    x = Caudalactual
    EffBomba = (((x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)) + Y1) / 100  aqui se presenta el error.
```

no hallo que hacer para eliminar el error y poder seguir, he declado las variables como double como long decimal e integer y nada,agradeceria su ayuda

Comment: Dónde te da el error? En qué línea?

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir más código? No veo el End Select que cierra el Select Case.

Comment: Cierto, tal y como te comenta Greydel estás declarando mal las variables.
En la primera línea con Dim ..... hasta Diametro as Double estás declarando todas las variables de esa línea como Variant, excepto Diametro.

Para declararlas todas como Double debes hacerlo así:

Dim py as Double, pb as Double, veltestactual as Double, etc. etc.... y así todas.En caso de no hacerlo así las estás declarando como Variant, tal y como te he comentado.

Prueba a declarar bien las variables y vuelve a ejecutar tú código.

Answer (score 1):

A veces, cuando declaras:

```
Dim var1, var2 as Double
```

Sucede que `var2` es `Double` pero `var1` es `variant`, luego le asignas a `var1` un valor y se define al menor posible, por ejemplo a byte.

Creo que es un **bug**.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es como comenta @Greydel, los tipos de variables no están especificados, por lo tanto los límites de éstos tipos provocan el error, está superando su capacidad de memoria.

```vb
Dim X1, X2, Y1, Y2, x As Double

Sub Operacion()
    Dim EffBomba As Double
    EffBomba = (((x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)) + Y1) / 100
End Sub
```

En el código anterior marcará error sin necesidad de ingresar valores, `x = 0`, pero `X1, X2, Y1, y Y2` son vacío, la inicialización del tipo sólo afectó a `x` como `Double` y las demás son `Variant`
Por lo anterior es necesaria la declaración en tu caso, entonces quedaría así:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()
    CommandButton5.BackColor = 12713921

    '===========================================================================================
    '                                    VARIABLES
    '===========================================================================================
    'i = 1000
    'Do Until Cells(i, 2) = ""
    'If i < 10 Then
    'End If
    Dim py As Double, pb As Double, veltestactual As Double, NFD As Double, API As Double, Tfondo As Double, BSW As Double, GravAgua As Double, Pcasing As Double, ViscoFluido As Double, ProfBomba As Double, PMP As Double, Caudaltestactual As Double, rppmoper As Double, PIPtomado As Double, Diametro As Double
    Dim THP As Double, Voltaje As Double, Corriente As Double, FactorPotencia As Double, LongitudCable As Double, EffMotor As Double, NumSellos As Double, EffBomba As Double
    Dim n As Double
    Dim X1 As Double, X2 As Double, Y1 As Double, Y2 As Double, x As Double

    case1 = ActiveCell.Row
    cases = Selection.Rows.Count
    lastcase = case1 + cases - 1

    'Return
    For n = case1 To lastcase

    'Pwf = Cells(n, 24)
    py = Cells(n, 17)
    pb = Cells(n, 9)
    veltestactual = Cells(n, 35)
    NFD = Cells(n, 23)
    API = Cells(n, 6)
    Tfondo = Cells(n, 10)
    BSW = Cells(n, 8)
    GravAgua = 1
    Pcasing = Cells(n, 50)
    ViscoFluido = Cells(n, 13)
    ProfBomba = Cells(n, 29)
    PMP = Cells(n, 28)
    Caudaltestactual = Cells(n, 48)
    rpmoper = Cells(n, 34)
    PIPtomado = Cells(n, 40)
    Diametro = Cells(n, 31)
    THP = Cells(n, 51)
    Voltaje = Cells(n, 41)
    Corriente = Cells(n, 37)
    FactorPotencia = Cells(n, 47)
    LongitudCable = Cells(n, 42)
    EffMotor = Cells(n, 43)
    NumSellos = 2

    '=================================================================
    '               CALCULO DEL CAUDAL ACTUAL
    '=================================================================

    Caudalactual = Caudaltestactual * (rpmoper / veltestactual)
    '==================================================================
    '              EFFICIENCIA DE LA BOMBA
    '==================================================================
    Select Case Caudalactual

    Case Is < 500
    X1 = 0
    X2 = 500
    Y1 = 0
    Y2 = 30
    x = Caudalactual
    EffBomba = (((x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)) + Y1) / 100

    Case 500.01 To 1000
    X1 = 500.01
    X2 = 1000
    Y1 = 30
    Y2 = 46
    x = Caudalactual
    EffBomba = (((x - X1) * (Y2 - Y1) / (X2 - X1)) + Y1) / 100  aqui se presenta el error.
```